# How should I implement this secondary thread to avoid errors? (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, error-handling

I am implementing in my Android app a splash screen which:

- dowloads a sqlite database from a server
- loads urls to get JSONs
- creates a sqlite database in the device and execute several queries

I am using AsyncTask to do everything, my problem will occur if the user close the app in the middle of the process or turn off the device because the app:

- could be creating a database or executing crucial queries in the device
- could be downloading the sqlite db from a server
- could be running several important process
- etc

Definitely, the entire process (3-5 seconds) is important.

So... How could I avoid this? should I use handlers, loaders, on-(pause, stop, destroy) methods in order to get my objective? Can you give me an example?

Comment: You need to execute this code in service This will solve problem with your app close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, you should use a service as their lifecycle is separate to that of the activity.

Create the service like so:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Do everything you need to here, then call stop:
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Started...");

        stopSelf();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.androidexample.SERVICE_STOPPING");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Then in the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ServiceCompleteReceiver receiver;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IntentFilter filter;

        receiver = new ServiceCompleteReceiver();
        filter = new IntentFilter("com.example.androidexample.SERVICE_STOPPING");
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }


    public class ServiceCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Do whatever needs to be done here

            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        }

    }

}
```

**EDIT :**

Don't forget to add it to your manifest as well

```
   <service
        android:name="com.example.androidexample.MyService"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </service>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a good solution for me but: how can I know if the service is finished? how can I publish information from the service to the UI? And what if the user turn off the device?

Comment: You can use LocalBroadcastManager from support library or more advanced Otto from Square http://square.github.io/otto/. Basically, you register your activity to receive actions sent from your service.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a broadcast receiver as well. Now, when the service is destroyed, the activity will be notified, and the `onReceive` method of the `ServiceCompleteReceiver` will be called

Comment: Regarding the user turning off the device, you should register for the ACTION_SHUTDOWN broadcast as well, and then handle that as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks very much. Do you think that I should execute the service in a secondary thread or in the main?

Comment: If you're accessing the SQLite db using the network, you will have to use a secondary thread otherwise Android throws a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.